# How to bind data value with checkbox (checked or unchecked )

Tags: angular, checkbox

I have a few checkboxes and on Checked event I am submitting the data id back to server instead of the true or false value, but I am not able to bind checkbox status after reloading the page. How can I check if the checkbox value exists in database?

This is My HTML code

```
<span *ngFor = "let groupid of result" >
                        <ng-container *ngIf ="regTypeSelectedOption === 'my group'">
                      <div *ngFor="let group of my_groupList; let i = index" >
                             <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" value="{{group._id}"
                                 [name]="videodisplaygroup"
                              [checked] = "group._id ==groupid.id"

                                 (change)="getCheckboxValues($event,group)" />
                                <span innerHTML="{{group.group_name}}"></span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </ng-container>
                </span >
```

Comment: What does the server return telling you that a particular group is checked?

Comment: Onclick check box I am saving group id instead of true false,

Comment: this way saving in database `videodisplaygroup: Array(2)
0: "5c9b52580737ae188c5be14b"
1: "5c8f6c2ea2c9eb1418f8fb1b"`

Comment: Right, so how to you differentiate between a checked and unchecked groups because on front end you will have group ids for both of them, isn't it?

Comment: and here what I want if this two id is exist in database then only that particular checkbox should be checked

Comment: Okay so you get a response from the server which contains an array containing only the checked ids?

Comment: yes checkbox id or you can group id

Comment: Hi,
Are you there ? Please

Comment: @xyz I  haven't found any solution so far please help me

Comment: Oh, okay , somewhat busy now. Have a look at this if this fixes it, or else I will see your question in 4-5 hours. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h8p8re?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: sure, I will try with this way .

Comment: @xyz Thanks a lot man really your demo worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to look into [reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)

```
<input type="checkbox" [fromControl]="myValue"/>
```

Code

```
myValue = new FormControl(); // property inside of component class
myValue.valueChanges.subscribe((v)=>{ console.log('value changed')}); // Can be in constructor or ngInit
myValue.setValue(true| false) // When your server returns data
```

Comment: when getting data from server ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set `[(ngModel)]="fromDB.checked"` in input tag

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox{{fromDB.docId}}" 
  [(ngModel)]="fromDB.checked" (change)="checkboxClicked()" />
```

Assume data from DB

```
fromDB = 
    {
      docId:1,
      docName:'Test name',
      checked: true
    };
```

With your source code change to

```
<div *ngFor="let group of my_groupList; let i = index" >
    <label>
      <input 
          type="checkbox"
          value="{{group._id}"
          [(ngModel)] = "group.checked"
          [name]="videodisplaygroup"       
          (change)="getCheckboxValues($event,group)" />
      <span innerHTML="{{group.group_name}}"></span>
    </label>
  </div>
```

Update:

With updated code, you dont need use 2 loop, you should handle my_groupList add a property checked base on result object. This line `checked: this.result.find(d => d.id == c._id)` confirm that what item is checked.

```
this.my_groupList = this.my_groupList.map(c => 
  { return { _id: c._id, group_name: c.group_name, 
    checked: this.result.find(d => d.id == c._id) }; 
  })
```

Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gru8a2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: but I am little bit confused

Comment: Actually I am getting group list from database  then using ngfor I am displaying group list with checkbox then after that I am saving checkbox value in same database but different place not back to where I am getting group list

Comment: So How can run  2 loop ?

Comment: are  you there ?

Comment: I saw only 1 loop in your code? where is 2 loops? update your question?

Comment: I mean one loop for first time displaying group list and second loop may be for binding id with checkbox.

Comment: Can I have your skype id so that I can show you view page as well. Please

Comment: Sure, I will try with this way then will get back to you

Answer (score 0):

In started, you create a Array List with the help of selected array and database array(Full Array List).
      **custom =  {
                id: number,
                name : string,
                checked : boolean;
                }**

Like : -

```
 full_Array [] = [{id:1, name= "mohan"},{id:1, name= "Sachin"},{id:1,name= "Azhar"}]
 selected_Array [] = [{id:1, name= "Sachin"}]  // data come from API
 own_Array [] = [];
```

Now created your own Array List -

```
          for(let j=0; j< selected_Array.length; j++){
               for(let i=0; i< full_Array.length; i++){
                  if(selected_Array[j].id === full_Array[i].id ){
                      var data = new this.custom();
                           data.id = selected_Array[j].id;
                           data.name = selected_Array[j].name;
                           data.selected = true;
                           this.own_Array.push(data);
                     }else{
                           var data = new this.custom();
                           data.id = selected_Array[j].id;
                           data.name = selected_Array[j].name;
                           data.selected = false;
                           this.own_Array.push(data);
                         }
               }
                   }

<tr *ngFor="let contactCard of own_Array">
 <td>
  <input type="checkbox" name="optionsCheckboxes" checked="" 
        [(ngModel)]="contactCard.selected" (change)="checkContact(contactCard)" required>
 </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Here checkbox is binding but what is happening here if select more than one  checkbox then after submitting when I reload the page  then loop is showing two time